# Resharper: Customize 'Create and initialize auto-property' - private setter

Tags: c#, resharper

When creating matching properties for constructor parameters, I mostly want the setters to be private. With out-of-the-box functionality in Resharper, the contextual 'Create and initialize auto-property "NNN"' does create a property with both the getter and the setter with public visibility.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: It does not appear that you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613316/how-to-change-default-access-modifier-in-resharper-r-to-internal